# SPF DKIM PTR seem good, but still marked as spam

Tags: php, email, gmail, spf, dkim

TL;DR 
SPF ad DKIM pass, PRT record complete, no blacklisted ip, not spammy message, but they still go to spam.

Gmail (and most other mail hosts) are marking my messages as spam. They're not spam, they're purchase receipts, upcoming class reminders and thank you notes for attending a class. All sent from my bespoke database driven system, that looks for upcoming classes, and pulls the message and email addresses (and first names) from the database and sends the message.

It's been working fine for a couple of years, but I noticed a few months ago customers started complaining they weren't getting the mail they expected. It's now at the point where no Gmail user receive my messages to their inbox. Most other servers also flag as spam.

So I signed up for a VPS, to get away from possible bad server neighbors. I read up a lot on SPF and DKIM, and believe I have them set correctly. PTR seems to resolve to the right domain.

The email is not spammy at all, no content changes have any effect (including very simple plain text messages). They are currently HTML with a few linked images, including one open tracking pixel (src of spacer.phpid=12345). They include an unsub link. I also think I do follow the guidelines for sending mail set out by Google. There are very few html links, most are simple text that are linkafied by Gmail.

I'd be happy to provide any information you need that might help, but may need to be told how to provide, ie where will I get it for you. I'm not a total noob, but am new to VPS.

Personal details (domains, email addresses and IPs) have been obfuscated, but will message the original headers to anyone who can help. Link addresses have also been broken (changes to example.com intentionally).

DMIK is enabled through cPanel
SPF record set up by host is

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:123.456.7.20 +ip4:123.456.7.207 -all
```

Here's the original message headers from the received message in the spam folder

```
Delivered-To: sentotaddress@gmail.com
Received: by 10.36.120.193 with SMTP id p184csp1956256itc;
        Tue, 19 Apr 2016 11:25:11 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.50.167.2 with SMTP id zk2mr5499232igb.2.1461090311026;
        Tue, 19 Apr 2016 11:25:11 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <info@example.com>
Received: from vps.example.com (vps.example.com. [123.456.7.20])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id lo2si6108912igb.89.2016.04.19.11.25.10
        for <sentotaddress@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 19 Apr 2016 11:25:10 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@example.com designates 123.456.7.20 as permitted sender) client-ip=123.456.7.20;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@example.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@example.com designates 123.456.7.20 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=info@example.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=example.com; s=default; h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:
    Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Reply-To:From:Date:Subject:To;
    bh=l630T1O7H48Yzm8wbX3YlSOHH9n09reeSZJ7fdMuFOs=; b=vfiNWlzAJpR4W9n4FJoelK5Oqy
    vcpUoHMF2vZ4DWRuzYsMzV7MCA2kUhdf8Bd81oJf6+AiOpsGNFNT9dzhbOUwc1ytTc1LdiYtiTY2M
    +fvaCp5N+/QgUbmhDc5godo0godZaPxZ2qUztGBEdQTc7j9zBkdTJey8/UX/mtTMQjr6uTyb/5k3T
    wG3ZCK+P+RM9ZxG8Z2e41bHEqm/Rag8mFQp3t558ZZgOvrUzjl+gQ8Dzs0vPQWqimFeUt2q1BcxQ8
    AKCd15+2zWOCfxEPuymclTTQcn3+ZZj5VRRVMSpECRwXe4nz0kleX4G4T4CMqzpSe4av7MC6MGhuO
    +0qhiGAA==;
Received: from hostaccountname by vps.example.com with local (Exim 4.86_1)
    (envelope-from <info@example.com>)
    id 1asaKc-0002YD-NS
    for sentotaddress@gmail.com; Tue, 19 Apr 2016 12:25:02 -0600
To: sentotaddress@gmail.com
Subject: Test 409
X-PHP-Script: example.com/cron_mass_mailer.php for 123.456.7.207
Date: Tue, 19 Apr 2016 12:25:02 -0600
From: Simon lastname <info@example.com>
Reply-To: Simon lastname <info@example.com>
Message-ID: <dcdd902d9d1e0ff42ee195a8e17b2562@example.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_dcdd902d9d1e0ff42ee195a8e17b2562"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - vps.example.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [501 512] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - example.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: vps.example.com: authenticated_id: hostaccountname/from_h
X-Authenticated-Sender: vps.example.com: info@example.com

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--b1_dcdd902d9d1e0ff42ee195a8e17b2562
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

14 address, city, sa 12345


Hi Simon,

Great to see you last night, I always enjoy catching up with you guys. And thanks for letting me test this out. I hope it makes it into your inbox!

If it doesn't, could copy and paste and results from any spam filter, or headers, to see if there's any clues to see where the issues are.

Thanks!
Me



~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Me
Tel/SMS: (123) 123-1231
https://example.com




Connect online
Unsubscribe from newsletter here https://example.com/unsubscribe


--b1_dcdd902d9d1e0ff42ee195a8e17b2562
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body style="font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<table style="width:580px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p style="text-align:center;font-size:18px;padding-bottom:12px;margin-bottom:18px;border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;"><img src="https://example.com/images/htmlemail/logo120.png" alt="Logo png" align="center" style="margin:auto;width:100px;"><br><br/><span style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;">007 The St. Colo Spgs, CO 80903</span></p>


<p>Hi Simon,<br />
<br />
Great to see you last night, I always enjoy catching up with you guys. And thanks for letting me test this out. I hope it makes it into your inbox!<br />
<br />
If it doesn't, could copy and paste and results from any spam filter, or headers, to see if there's any clues to see where the issues are.<br />
<br />
Thanks!<br />
Me<br />
<br />
<br/><img src="https://example.com/images/htmlemail/spacer.php?spacer=13654"></p>
            <p  style="font-size:12px;">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<br/>
Me<br/>
Tel/SMS: (123) 123-1231<br/>
https://example.com<br/>
<br/>

<a href="https://twitter.com/mytwitter"><img src="https://example.com/images/htmlemail/twitter25.png" alt="Follow me on Twitter" style="margin:0 10px 0 0;"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/mydomain"><img src="https://example.com/images/htmlemail/facebook25.png" alt="Like us on Facebook" style="margin:0 10px 0 0;"></a>
<br/>Connect online</p>
<p style="font-size:11px;">Unsubscribe from newsletter here https://example.com/unsubscribe</p>
        </td>
    </td>
</table>
</body>
</html>



--b1_dcdd902d9d1e0ff42ee195a8e17b2562--
```

Comment: PHP version is 5.4.45, I think you're looking at the PHPMailer version, which is a class. 5.4.45  was on the newly installed  VPS, and was only recently unsupported. I plan to upgrade, but one thing at a time. So would that have any effect on my issue?

Comment: 5.4 is still EOL but should be sufficient for doing what you're trying here.